# How would I extend a Pandas DataFrame such as this?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following DataFrame from Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'age 15-19':10, 'age 20-30':100, 'Gender': 'F'}, {'age 15-19':11,'age 20-30':110, 'Gender': 'M'}, {'age 15-19':12,'age 20-30':120, 'Gender': 'F'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       age_15-19   age_20-30    Gender
0         10          100         F
1         11          110         M
2         12          120         F
```

And I'd like to turn it into a different table such as this:

```
          Age       Gender    Number
0         15-19       F         10
1         15-19       M         11
2         15-19       F         12
3         20-30       F         100
4         20-30       M         110
5         20-30       F         120
```

But I have no idea how to code it. Is that possible on Pandas? How would I proceed? I'm still a rookie in Python and Programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Gender'], value_vars=['age 15-19','age 20-30'], var_name='Age', value_name='Number')
```

---

**Output**

```
    Gender  Age Number
0   F   age 15-19   10
1   M   age 15-19   11
2   F   age 15-19   12
3   F   age 20-30   100
4   M   age 20-30   110
5   F   age 20-30   120
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `set_index` and `unstack`

```
res = df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.strip('age ')).set_index('Gender').unstack().reset_index(name='number').rename(columns={'level_0': 'Age'})
```

---

**res:**

```
    Age      Gender number
0   15-19   F   10
1   15-19   M   11
2   15-19   F   12
3   20-30   F   100
4   20-30   M   110
5   20-30   F   120
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Hey ,you can try something like this.
import pandas as pd

# Creating the first Dataframe using dictionary
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4],
                    "b":[5, 6, 7, 8]})

# Creating the Second Dataframe using dictionary
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3],
                    "b":[5, 6, 7],
                    "c":[1, 5, 4]})

# for appending df2 at the end of df1
df1.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Super easy with `pivot_longer` from [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), just like the one from `tidyr` in `R`:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datar.all import f, pivot_longer
>>> 
>>> inp = [
...     {"age 15-19": 10, "age 20-30": 100, "Gender": "F"},
...     {"age 15-19": 11, "age 20-30": 110, "Gender": "M"},
...     {"age 15-19": 12, "age 20-30": 120, "Gender": "F"},
... ]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
>>> df
   age 15-19  age 20-30   Gender
     <int64>    <int64> <object>
0         10        100        F
1         11        110        M
2         12        120        F
>>> df >> pivot_longer(
...     ~f.Gender,
...     names_to="Age",
...     values_to="Number",
...     names_prefix="age ",
... )
    Gender      Age  Number
  <object> <object> <int64>
0        F    15-19      10
1        M    15-19      11
2        F    15-19      12
3        F    20-30     100
4        M    20-30     110
5        F    20-30     120
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `datar` package.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to strip the age prefix before `melting`:

```
(df.rename(columns=lambda col: col.lstrip('age '))
 .melt('Gender', value_name='Number', var_name='Age')
 )

  Gender    Age  Number
0      F  15-19      10
1      M  15-19      11
2      F  15-19      12
3      F  20-30     100
4      M  20-30     110
5      F  20-30     120
```

Another option would be via `pivot_longer` from `pyjanitor` -> one way to solve this would be to pass a regex with a group, denoting which part of the column label we are interested in:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn
df.pivot_longer(index = 'Gender', 
                names_to='Age', 
                names_pattern=r'.{4}(.+)', 
                values_to='Number')

      Gender    Age  Number
0      F  15-19      10
1      M  15-19      11
2      F  15-19      12
3      F  20-30     100
4      M  20-30     110
5      F  20-30     120
```

Another option would be to use a separator to split the age columns on the whitespace, and after that keep only the required columns:

```
(df.pivot_longer('Gender', 
                 names_to=['word','Age'], 
                 names_sep = ' ', values_to='Number')
   .drop(columns='word')
)
 
  Gender    Age  Number
0      F  15-19      10
1      M  15-19      11
2      F  15-19      12
3      F  20-30     100
4      M  20-30     110
5      F  20-30     120
```